# Why does trigonometric integration behave differently

Tags: calculus

In the case of $$\int \cos^2x\, dx= \frac{1}{2}\left [ x\sin x \cos x \right ]$$
Why doesn't it behave as $$\int \cos^n x\, dx= \frac{1}{n-1}\left( \sin x \right)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Don't forget the additional term in chain rule.

Comment: $\int \cos^2x\, dx= \frac{1}{2}\left [ x\sin x \cos x \right ]$ or $\int \cos^2x\, dx= \frac{1}{2}\left [ x+\sin x \cos x \right ]$?

Comment: How you get $\int \cos^n x\, dx= \frac{1}{n-1}\left( \sin x \right)^{n-1}$

Comment: I think it should be $\frac{1}{2}[x+\sin x \cos x ]$ because $\cos^2>0$ and therefor the integral has to be monotone increasing...

Comment: Neither $\int \cos^2x\, dx= \frac{1}{2}\left [ x\sin x \cos x \right ]$ nor $\int \cos^n x\, dx= \frac{1}{n-1}\left( \sin x \right)^{n-1}$ is a correct statement.

Comment: I think he ment $\int \cos^nx dx= \frac{1}{n+1}\sin^{n+1}x$ like in $\int x^n dx = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$

Comment: It all relies on the rule $\int f'(x)[f(x)]^n dx = \frac{1}{n+1}[f(x)]^{n+1}+C$. If you don't have the derivative, you can't do it your method.

Answer (score 1):

We have$$\int \cos^2 x dx= \sin x\cos x+\int (1-\cos^2 x)dx=\frac12(\sin x\cos x+x)$$

and $$\int cos^n x dx=\frac1n\cos^{n-1}x\sin x+\frac{n-1}n\int cos^{n-2}xdx$$for n>0

Answer (score 0):

$$\int -\cos^nx \sin x dx=\frac{1}{n-1}\cos^{n-1}x$$ 
$$\int \sin^nx \cos x dx=\frac{1}{n-1}\sin^{n-1}x$$

so, I think the second integral not correct